# Retrieving json data in Custom ListView?

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview, android-volley

I am parsing a JSON Data with Volley library and I retrieve the data in ListView but only the last value is printed.. Here is my implementation :

```
    public void getListElem(final Context context) {

    apws = new APWSManager(context, new APWSRequestState() {

        @Override
        public void customURLFinishedDownload(String response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("RESPONSE LISTVIEWPARSER : ", response);
            try {
                JSONObject json = null;
                JSONArray   array = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
                    json = array.getJSONObject(j);
                    Log.i("JSONOBJECT : ", json.toString());

                    parseJsonItem(json);
                    /*                      myItemList = new ItemObject(json.getString("title"), 
                            json.getString("value_out"), json.getString("picture")); */

                    //      m_ListItem.add(myItemList);

                    myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                    Log.i("LISTVIEW TITLE", array.getJSONObject(j).getString("title"));
                    Log.i("LISTVIEW VALUE", array.getJSONObject(j).getString("value_out"));
                    Log.i("LISTVIEW PICTURE", array.getJSONObject(j).getString("picture"));
                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void customURLFailedDownload(String errorMessage) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("ERROR REQUEST : ", errorMessage.toString());
        }
    });
    apws.callAPWSRequest("getnews", null, null, TypeMethod.GET, true);
}

private void parseJsonItem(JSONObject item) {
    try {
        ItemObject  itemObject = new ItemObject(item.getString("title"), item.getString("value_out"), item.getString("picture"));
        // Ici à la place tu ajoutes ton objet dans ton array
        m_ListItem.add(itemObject);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My ListView is printed correctly but always with the same value (the last value in json). How Can I do to retrieve each value in each item of my ListView ?

Thank you guys !

Comment: You are setting your list adapter with myAdapter but I'm not seeing any code that sets myAdapter with your m_ListItem that has the Json values added to it?

Comment: @SvenT23 I defined it but I don't shows the code : 

`  myList = (PullAndLoadListView) findViewById(R.id.refreshList);
  m_ListItem = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
  myAdapter = new ListToRefreshAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, m_ListItem);
`

Comment: And if you check your m_ListItem it's holding all the json data, not just the last value like your list is showing? If nothing else helps, I'd try to make a new adapter to set for your list to see if something's not working with the notifydatasetchanged. like `myList.setAdapter(new ListToRefreshAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, m_ListItem));` instead of the notifydatasetchanged and deleting the current `myList.setAdapter` inside of your for loop.